# Restarting exe processes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am testing out some ways to close the process of an exe; I am using my Discord application for the testing as it has identifiable ways to see whether it's been restarted (splash screen).

The problem is that it will close the process (slowly), but it will not restart - even with the code giving the code which makes it restart.

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

let LOCAL = process.env.LOCALAPPDATA

async function processTest() {
    const clients = [
        'Discord.exe',
        'DiscordCanary.exe',
        'discordDevelopment.exe',
        'DiscordPTB.exe'
    ];

    try {
        const { stdout } = await exec('tasklist');

        for (const client of clients) {
            if (stdout.includes(client)) {
                await exec(`taskkill /F /T /IM ${client}`); // kill process
                await exec(`"${LOCAL}\\${client.replace('.exe', '')}\\Update.exe" --processStart ${client}`); // restart process
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
    }
}
processTest();
module.exports = processTest;
```

I have tried using things like process-tree, but I do not feel comfortable relying on a package that much in this project.

Comment: Check what the expression in your second `exec` evaluates to abd then try executing that in PowerShell or CMD. Does it work?